# Conditional statement to check if NSData contains certain value

Tags: ios, if-statement, nsdata

I tried the code below and it is not working. I am trying to test whether `NSData` is nil or not to assign to image. This is the code i have tried:

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

NSLog(@"image data %@",imageData);

if ( imageData== nil) {
    NSLog(@"NO IMAGE");
    imageSection.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noPic"];
}else{
imageSection.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

The logged image data returns the response below when an image is not present:

```
imageData <>
```

So i was wondering how to check if if NSData contains this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this:

```
if (imageData.length > 0) {
    //imageData have some value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An NSData object can have no data, so comparing the reference to nil wont work.
But NSData has a length property. If that is greater than 0 then there is data in the object.